# object 型データから int 型への変換でエラーが発生する

Tags: python, pandas

csvで読み込んだデータがobject型として読み込まれてしまい、int型への変換を実施したところ添付のようなエラーでつまずいてしまっております。
色々やり方は調べたのですがどうしても解決できないため、解決方法を教示いただけると幸いです。

おそらく空欄が影響してしまっているのでreplaceでnp.NaNにした上でastypeにてint型変換をかけたのですがうまくいっていない状況です。

csvファイル：
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a0uwjrnOBXi0MIpmpeY6UpyeL4YVYIlL/view?usp=sharing

実行コード

```
main = pd.read_csv("サンプルデータ.csv")
main.head()

文字列型が入っている
print(main['PS_01_B00004031'].dtype)
#object

NaN(Not a Number) にしたい
main = main.replace(' ', np.nan)
main

数値型へ変換する
main = main.astype('int', errors='ignore')
main

main.dtypes.value_counts()
##int32      967
object     603
float64     34
dtype: int64
```

結果
objectが残ってしまっている

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [Pandas で欠損値を含む整数型を扱う](https://qiita.com/hoto17296/items/b6c90db4b9bcdb7b6d78), [pandas 1.2.0+ での pd.NA の特徴](https://qiita.com/hkzm/items/52195729e9b00ae88789) 2つ目の記事の [read_csv での指定](https://qiita.com/hkzm/items/52195729e9b00ae88789#read_csv-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A) を適用してみてはどうでしょう？ それから対象のcsvデータは入手方法やリンクを記載するか、問題を再現できる程度にサイズを縮小して記事にテキストで記述した方がよいでしょう。

Comment: @kunif 様　ありがとうございます。read csvでの指定を試みたところvalue errorが出てしまったので下記記事を参照に一度float型に変換してからできないか試してみます。また記載方法もありがとうございます。テキストで記載するよういたします。https://dev.to/itsmycode/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-4klg#:~:text=ValueError%3A%20invalid%20literal%20for%20int%20%28%29%20with%20base,method%20to%20convert%20your%20number%20to%20an%20integer.

Comment: 空欄の値を `0` にしてから `as_type` を実行するなど。`main.replace('', 0).astype(int, errors='ignore')` もっとも、`0` にすることでデータの意味を変化させてしまうことになるかもしれませんが。

Comment: それから、`main.replace('', 'NaN')` としている部分がありますが、これは `NaN` という文字列に置き換えることになります。`NaN`(Not a Number) にしたいのであれば `main.replace('', np.nan)` とします。

Comment: 途中で`In [17]: main.replace(' ', 'NaN')`としているので、数字が入っていない欄には空白1文字が入っていると思われますが、それをどのような値にしたいのでしょうか？ その列のデータ型を整数のままにしたいのであれば、`0`なり`-1`なり、何かの有効な整数値にするか、私の最初のコメントで紹介した記事のようにpandasの`Int64`の`NA`(表示の時は`<NA>`となる)に変換することになるのでは？

Comment: コードやエラーメッセージは画像キャプチャではなく、なるべく文字のまま質問に貼り付けてください。

Comment: 失礼いたしました。再度ファイルと実施したコードをテキストで記載しなおしました。やりたいこととしては空欄になってしまっている箇所にNaNを挿入した上でobject型をすべてint型に変換したいと考えております。

Comment: @issei `np.nan` は `float` 型ですので、`NaN` が含まれているかぎり `int`型に変換することはできません(`float`型への変換は可能です)。

Comment: @issei `Int64` 型でもよいのであれば `main.replace(' ', np.nan).astype(float).astype('Int64')` とすることはできます。

Comment: 0でない数値型に直せれば問題なかったので一旦main.replace('　', ‐1)に置き換えることで解決できました。本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: 一応、`main = pd.read_csv("サンプルデータ.csv").replace(' ', -1).astype(int)` としてもよろしいかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

コメントで紹介した記事のように、読み込み時に空白を削除して`Int64`に変換すればすべての列は整数`Int64`型になり、空欄は`pandas.NA`となって`<NA>`と表示されます。
@metropolisさんがコメントしているように、`NaN`はnumpyのnp.nanで浮動小数点の`Not a Number`なので、それが含まれるなら整数型にはなりません。
[Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

> Changed in version 1.0.0: Now uses pandas.NA as the missing value rather than numpy.nan.
>
> In Working with missing data, we saw that pandas primarily uses NaN to represent missing data. Because NaN is a float, this forces an array of integers with any missing values to become floating point. In some cases, this may not matter much. But if your integer column is, say, an identifier, casting to float can be problematic. Some integers cannot even be represented as floating point numbers.

[pandas 1.2.0+ での pd.NA の特徴](https://qiita.com/hkzm/items/52195729e9b00ae88789)
[Pandas で欠損値を含む整数型を扱う](https://qiita.com/hoto17296/items/b6c90db4b9bcdb7b6d78)

こんな感じで読み込み時に1行で指定することができます。

```
df = pd.read_csv('サンプルデータ.csv', skipinitialspace=True, dtype='Int64')
```

リンク先に紹介されたサンプルデータを使った結果はこうなります。

```
Python 3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('サンプルデータ.csv', skipinitialspace=True, dtype='Int64')
>>> df
    SampleID  SEX_CD  AGE  MARRIAGE  CHILD_CD  CHILD_CD2  CHILD_AGE_1  ...  PS_01_B00004165  PI_02_B00004165  PS_02_B00004165  PI_01_B00004166  PS_01_B00004166  PI_02_B00004166  PS_02_B00004166
0    1160001       1   48         1         2          5         <NA>  ...                5                5                5                5                4                5                4
1    1160002       1   51         2         2       <NA>         <NA>  ...                4             <NA>             <NA>                5                4             <NA>             <NA>
2    1160003       2   55         2         1          1           25  ...             <NA>                4                5             <NA>             <NA>                4                4
3    1160005       1   39         2         1          2           14  ...                4                5                4                5                4                5                4
4    1160006       1   56         2         1          2           26  ...                4                5                4                4                4                5                4
5    1160009       1   59         2         1          2           31  ...                5                5                4                5                4                5                4
6    1160010       2   57         2         1          2           31  ...                5                5                5                5                4                5                4
7    1160014       1   48         2         1          1           22  ...                3                3                3                4                4                3                4
8    1160015       1   53         2         1          3           15  ...                4                5                4                5                4                5                4
9    1163964       1   34         2         2       <NA>         <NA>  ...                5                5                5                5                5                5                5
10   1163965       2   22         1         2       <NA>         <NA>  ...             <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             <NA>
11   1163966       1   20         1         2          5         <NA>  ...                5                5                5                5                5                5                5
12   1163969       1   49         2         1          1            9  ...                5                5                5                5                5                5                5
13   1163970       2   37         2         1          1            4  ...                5                5                5                5                5                5                5
14   1163972       1   39         2         2       <NA>         <NA>  ...                4                4                3                5                4                5                4
15   1163974       1   30         2         2       <NA>         <NA>  ...                4                3                3                3                4                3                4
16   1163975       1   58         1         2          5         <NA>  ...                4                5                4                5                4                5                4
17   1163977       1   28         1         2       <NA>         <NA>  ...                5                3                5                3                4                3                4
18   1163980       1   22         1         2       <NA>         <NA>  ...                4             <NA>             <NA>                3                4             <NA>             <NA>
19   1163981       2   20         1         2          5         <NA>  ...                5                4                4                4                5                4                4
20   1163983       2   31         1         2          5         <NA>  ...                5                4                5                5                4                4                4

[21 rows x 1604 columns]
>>> df.dtypes.value_counts()
Int64    1604
dtype: int64
>>>
```